# Built in transitions for fragment navigation

Tags: android, animation, navigation, fragment, transition

I have searched everywhere for an answer to the problem below without success.

I understand that there are two ways of visually connecting fragments during navigation: namely animations and transitions.

I have understood and used animations to connect two fragments but now I want to use the set transitions, not animations.

Here is the problem: I have two fragments, when the current fragment is replaced I want the second one to slide in - I suspect that using a built-in transition is simpler than an animation.

I get stuck at [this point](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#set-transitions) in the android developer's guide - only a code snippets are shown - what would the full xml resource file look like ?

All insights welcome

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just required a calm and close re-study of the Android Developer's guide on the 'Transitions Framework' and also The classes `Fragment`, `Transition`, `TransitionManager`, `Fade`, `Slide`.

My initial panic was caused by Android Studio opening a new xml file from the transition directory with an auto-template that began with the root tag `<transitionManager>` but files in the res/transition directory can begin with roots `<transitionManager>`,`<transitionSet>`, `<transition>` or simply the name of one of the built-in transitions such as `<slide>` with the parameters of the slide as attributes.